# Hover one DIV affecting another DIV: Why takes two taps on portable devices?

Tags: ios, css, hover, touchscreen

After I have implemented "hover one DIV - affecting another inner DIV" I noticed strange misbehavior on **iPad/iPhones**. Now it takes **two taps to click on the  link** in the DIV with hover code:

HTML:

```
<div class="portfblock">
    <div id="portfblock1_imgdiv"> <a href="http://photoRadosti.com" target="_blank"> 
                <div class="portfblock_imgdiv_txt_dsc_over">Baby &amp; Family Photography</div> 
              </a>
    </div>
    <!-- #portfblock1_imgdiv -->
    <div id="portfblock_desc"> <a href="http://photoRadosti.com" target="_blank">photoRadosti.com</a>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- #portfblock -->
```

CSS:

```
.portfblock:hover .portfblock_imgdiv_txt_dsc_over {
    visibility: visible; 
}
```

First tap only executes on-hover action (the sub-div with the class .*portfblock_imgdiv_txt_dsc_over* becomes visible as needed by hover), and only the second tap executes the href link jump.

My whole page to look at the misbehavior from iPad/iPhone is [here](http://bubencode.com/portfolio.html).

And the snippets of HTML and CSS code with one of the section to check are here at JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bubencode/5doLj02e/

It works fine on computer with the mouse, but it takes **two taps on touchscreens** to go to the links in websites thumbnails.

Might be anyone also faced the same effect? Is it possible to omit hover action while tapping on the div with hover from touchscreen devices, and to have the link href jump right after the first tap?

Would appreciate your help!

@bubencode

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer but nesting a div inside of a href isn't a good idea. It's a block level tag which may be causing this weird behavior. move the class on the div up to the href tag, then remove the div

Comment: @MattLambert: Thanks, I've heard that this is a bad style. But could you please clarify how to avoid this? What is meant by "move the class on the div up to the href tag, then remove the div"? Thank you.

Comment: @SleekGeek: I tried to be most specific and have put all the code snippet on JSFiddle. What else should I do? Thanks.

Comment: What shouldn't be showing on hover and what should be showing?

Comment: add the class to the href tag <a class="portfblock_imgdiv_txt_dsc_over" href="#">Baby &amp; Family Photography</a> or wrap the div around the href tag instead of inside it

Comment: @MattLambert: Thank you for your recommendations. 
1) If I wrap the div around the href tag I will not have the whole div clickable (while I need this). 
2) Adding class to the href tag seems reasonable. But <a> element can not have width and height. Aha, adding `display: block;` helps with this. Hurrah! =) [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bubencode/5doLj02e/6/)

Comment: Yes, use display:block on your href if you want the whole area clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way hover works on mobile devices. Since the concept of "hover" doesn't exist if you don't have a cursor the choice was to trigger hover on the first tap and click on the second. The reasoning was most likely to not break sites using hover for example when showing drop-down menus or similar.

If the hover is meaningless on touch-devices, consider detecting this and removing it, making your website responsive.

Comment: Yes he is exactly right, there is no hover state on a mobile device